# SQL Time in 1/100th format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have time in a varchar field that has content like the following
0.80, 0.94, 4.07
I want to show this time in minutes for example
00:48 instead of 0.80
What is the formula I would use to translate the time?

Comment: What is the RDBMs ?

Comment: Sorry Microsoft Sql

Comment: '00:' + cast(round(cast(value as decimal(6,2) * 60 * 100,0)) as varchar(2))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (col varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('0.80'),('0.94'),('4.07')

Select *
      ,Formatted = Format(DateAdd(SS,60*cast(col as float),0),'mm:ss')
 from @YourTable
```

If Not 2012+, try

```
,Formated = convert(varchar(8),DateAdd(SS,60*cast(col as float),0),108)
```

Returns

```
col     Formated
0.80    00:48
0.94    00:56
4.07    04:04
```

Comment: That works :) - the not 2012 part

Any chance I could get a little explanation on what it does, specifically the DateAdd part, I get the multiplying part but what is the SS again?

Comment: @MatthewJakachira Happy it helped.  Format() was introduced in SQL 2012.   So if 2008 and prior, we convert the datetime to a varchar(8) using the conversion type of 108